# How to make a scale only change height of a view?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I know ScaleTo can create an animation of a view.

but it will change the height and width,Is there anyway to change it's height by an animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the method `LayoutTo`.

For example

#### in xaml

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
    <BoxView x:Name="box" WidthRequest="300" BackgroundColor="Red" HeightRequest="600"  />
    <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked"  Text="Click Me"/>
</StackLayout>
```

#### in Code Behind

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   await box.LayoutTo(new Rectangle(box.Bounds.X, box.Bounds.Y, box.Bounds.Width, 300), 500, Easing.CubicIn);
}
```

For more details about different animation you can check https://trailheadtechnology.com/xamarin-forms-fancy-animations/